# create file in different directories with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rake, require

I'm new to ruby. Actually I'm trying to create an empty file "myfile.txt" in each of the following directories:

```
../../../../../TESTS/Test_A/myTest_A/
../../../../../TESTS/Test_B/myTest_B/
../../../../../TESTS/Test_C/myTest_C/
../../../../../TESTS/Test_D/myTest_D/
```

As you can see, the name of the Top directory is "TEST" and than after this, every directory have a different name but starts with "Test_", and than each "Test_*" directory contains only one directory and there my file should go in. I'm trying something like this:

```
require 'pathname'

def create_myFile
  pn = Pathname.new('../../../../../TESTS/Test_*/**')
  myFile = File.new("#{pn}/myFile.txt", "w+")
end
create_myFile
```

It doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: In Ruby: Best practice is to use lower case word separated by underscores for method names and instance variables. So create the method with `def create_my_file` and use the instance variable `my_file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pathname` does not accept wildcards. [`Dir#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) does:

```
Dir['../../../../../TESTS/Test_*/**'].each do |dir|
  File.new File.join(dir, 'myFile.txt'), 'w+'
end
```

Comment: By the way, I would like also to write something into the created file, and I'm trying to do it with open('myfile.txt', 'w') do |f| f.puts "This is my string"   (which is the next line after File.new File.join....) but it doesn't accept it?

Comment: `File.open('/tmp/a.txt', 'w+') do |f| f.puts "HELLO" end` ⇐ plus `'w+'` is required since the file is already existing and `File.open` should be used.

Comment: have tried it, but still nothing is written into the file

Comment: @milexy86 Please do not edit answers, changing the original code. You should substitute file name with the real one, that is apparently `File.join(dir, 'myFile.txt')`. If you have any other questions, besides the above, that is already perfectly answered, please ask _another question_.